# Laravel assigning the ID to a Zurb Foundation modal

Tags: laravel, zurb-foundation

I'm currently making a CMS, for a local charity (free of charge) and I'm using Laravel 5.6 along with Zurb foundation 6.4. It's my first time using Laravel, but I've really enjoyed it and I've almost finished.

However, I have a couple of little niggles, that I need to fix, before I deploy it and a little guidance would help, a lot. I'm stuck with assigning a dynamic ID to my modal, to update. My controller, route and model are fine. I can update the first record, from the table, with the modal and that works as expected.

The problem is, it is always the first record that is shown, irrespective of whether I click the trigger, on an unrelated row. I've tried to pass the category_id in, using Blade, but that doesn't work, I either get the same result or an error. I can see what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. I think I need some jQuery and/or Ajax and I have tried, to no avail (I'm rubbish with JS).

As I said, my MVC is sound, I can update the first row and all I need is to be able to dynamically assign the category_id to the data-open attribute. I'll post my code, below and thanks for taking time to read this.

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $category->posts->count() }}</td>
            <td align="center"><a data-open="editModal"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg" style="color: green"></i></a></td>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="{{ route('category.delete', ['id' => $category->id]) }}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg" style="color: red"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <div class="reveal" id="editModal" data-reveal>
            <h3>Edit: {{ $category->name }}</h3>
                <form action="{{ route('category.update', ['id' => $category->id]) }}" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <label for="name">Category Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $category->name }}">
                    <button class="button expanded success fullRadiusButton" type="submit">Update Category</button>
                    <a href="{{ route('categories') }}" class="close-button" aria-label="Close modal"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></a>
                </form>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Could you check your browser console to verify the right id is sent?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. At the moment no ID is being passed, as I couldn't get the ID to dynamically assign to the correct icon trigger. At the moment it is just retrieving the first record as I removed the bit of code I thought would assign it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element is unique in the document based on the `id` property but you're using the same id (`editModal`) multiple times. You're instructing the `Reveal Modal` library to open the modal with an `id` of `editModal` so it finds the first one (which it expects to be the only one) and opens it. An `id` should only ever appear once in a document, or you'll experience unexpected behaviour like this.

- `id` - unique to a single element
- `class` - not unique to an element

You can fix this by giving each edit modal a unique `id`, something like this:

```
<div class="reveal" id="editModal_{{ $category->id }}" data-reveal>
```

Then in your trigger reference that unique `id`:

```
<a data-open="editModal_{{ $category->id }}">
```

Comment: So simple, I thought I actually tried that. It works perfectly, so I obviously didn't try it just like that. Thank you, so much, you've just removed 1 headache from my weekend, I appreciate it. Now on to the next haha.

Comment: Brilliant, I really appreciate that, I may take you up on that offer, but I'm going to try to figure the little bugs out, first. I have until Monday, to get it done, which is when I told them I aim to deploy and I'm relatively confident I can do that. I only have 2 more functional elements to do and then I just need to tidy up a few bits of the UI. I'll try not to bother you, but if I get really stuck I will email and I appreciate that gesture, thank you.